Incomplete Bracket Order (TP set later)
In my algorithm, I can set the TP only when my buy/sell limit has been filled. More specifically, the tp only can be calculated when the current market price is around the buy/sell limit price.
I am using a code like the following to implement this. But the target does not work this way.
self.order_placed = False

if not self.order_placed:
    main_order = self.sell(
        price=limit_price,
        exectype=bt.Order.Limit,
        transmit=False,
        tradeid=self.soli_strategy_objects.very_next_tradeid,
    )
    
    stop_loss_order = self.buy(
        price=stop_loss_price,
        exectype=bt.Order.Stop,
        parent=main_order,
        transmit=True,
        tradeid=main_order.tradeid,
    )
    self.order_placed= True



if main_order.status in [bt.Order.Completed] and self.order_placed:
    tp_level = self.calculate_tp_level()
    Target_Order = self.buy(
                    price=tp_level,
                    exectype=bt.Order.Limit,
                    transmit=True,
                    parent=bracket_order_instance.main_order,
                    tradeid=bracket_order_instance.main_order.tradeid,
                )


But target order does not work. More specifically, it becomes "Accepted" and remains this way no matter what. (It is like a ghost order that doesn't exist at all)
Note that I cannot set "transmit" to False for the stop-loss order because in that case my main order does not get activated at all.
Any ideas?
I want the target order to be set whenever I want not necessarily at the same time as the parent order and the other child.

Am facing similar issue, did you come with a solution ? @abbas
